# Why is the "topics" argument of KafkaUtils.createStream() a Map rather then array?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Definition in docs:

> org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka
>
> Class KafkaUtils

```
static JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String,String> createStream(JavaStreamingContext jssc, String zkQuorum, String groupId, java.util.Map<String,Integer> topics)
```

> Create an input stream that pulls messages from Kafka Brokers.

Why is topics a Map (rather than a string array)?

I understand that the string key is the topic name. But what about the integer value? What should I fill in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the [Javadoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka/KafkaUtils.html):

> **public static JavaPairReceiverInputDStream createStream(JavaStreamingContext jssc,
>                                                          String zkQuorum,
>                                                          String groupId,
>                                                          java.util.Map topics)**
>
> Create an input stream that pulls messages from Kafka Brokers. Storage level of the data will be the default StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2.
>
> Parameters:
>      jssc - JavaStreamingContext object
>
> zkQuorum - Zookeeper quorum (hostname:port,hostname:port,..)
>
> groupId - The group id for this consumer
>
> topics - Map of (topic_name -> **numPartitions**) to consume. **Each partition is consumed in its own thread**
>
> Returns:
>      DStream of (Kafka message key, Kafka message value)

The value of the `Map` is the number of partitions of the given topic name, which determines the number of threads that will be used to consume the topic.

Answer (score 3):

If you see the documentation of the `createStream` method of `KafkaUtils` [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka/KafkaUtils.html), you'd see

> topics - Map of (topic_name -> numPartitions) to consume. Each partition is consumed in its own thread

The **Integer value** is the **number of partitions** for the topic as part of the key in the map.

Answer (score 1):

From Javadoc: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka/KafkaUtils.html

topics - Map of (topic_name -> numPartitions) to consume. Each partition is consumed in its own thread

so each number is the number of partitions you want to use for that topic